# Why tf.multinomial works with negative inputs like [[-1,1]]?

Tags: tensorflow

I guess `tf.multinomial` does sampling based on `softmax([[-1,1]])`. If you have some ideas, please, tell me.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `tf.multinomial` takes log-probabilities as its first argument.

From the docs:

> `logits`: 2-D Tensor with shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`. Each slice `[i, :]` represents the unnormalized log-probabilities for all classes.